# Improve ffmpeg x11grab screen capture performance

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-capture

I have been doing screen-only (no sound) capture using ffmpeg with libx264 for the encoding quite successfully on an old machine built around a Core2 Quad Q6600 processor. I now need to include audio in this, but the fans on this ancient machine are too loud. So, I found a fanless motherboard (https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/J5005-ITX/index.asp) that has an Intel Pentium Silver J5005 processor and decided to use this instead. The CPU's benchmarks put it in a similar bracket to the Q6600, and the general performance seems to be significantly better, presumably at least in part because it's now using DDR4 memory that's faster access.

However, the machine fails horribly at the screen capture. It's missing frames all over the place; I actually end up with video that's missing almost half the frames, and plays back at about double speed. Also, any audio is just messed up so badly I can hardly think how to describe it, best I can come up with is that I get perhaps a quarter second of sound then a few seconds pause (the video meanwhile is actually still playing back, albeit with no sense of time).

Some things occur to me that might be the cause, or cure, of my troubles, some of which I might be able to fix, others not so much. What other things should I try? (I'd prefer to avoid simply throwing money at the issue with random ideas that are baseless!)

1) perhaps the CPU lacks some "extensions" to the instruction set (I recall years ago some CPUs gaining MMX extensions") so that the CPU is fast at mundane computing but sucks at video encoding.

2) perhaps the fact that the old machine had a dedicated graphics card, while this new one is sharing main memory with the graphics system means that reading the screen pixels is much slower.

3) perhaps the fact that this new machine has a single DDR4 memory stick in it means that I'm forcing all the memory reads and writes for the computations through the same memory as is holding the screen, and that's too much (implying that adding an additional memory stick might jus possibly help?)

4) perhaps there's some bios setting that would allow more efficient sharing of video memory?

5) my favorite, perhaps there's a better compression library that I could use to get decent quality screen capture with much less CPU usage.

I should also note that I have tried this with -threads 0, and the CPU usage hovers between 100% and 200%; around 100% when the screen is static, and rising as I move windows around and otherwise create more output.

6) the motherboard claims to have some kind of hardware video encoder built into it. I haven't paid this any attention to this point, as I assumed it was for the purpose of taking HDMI input and encoding it, but maybe there's a way to use this, if so, what libraries might I need to get ffmpeg to do this.

Edits:

- This is an off the shelf ffmpeg. I'm certainly willing to try building it myself if I have some idea what I should do different.
- The motherboard claims to have hardware encoders, but I'm struggling to find out what they are (seems like it's an Intel chip called "UHD Graphics 605" but nothing I can find suggests ffmpeg can work with that)
- command line right now has been (without audio):

  ```
  ffmpeg  -video_size 1280x720   -f x11grab  -i ${DISPLAY}+100,100  -vcodec libx264  -f alsa -i pulse -acodec ac3 -threads 0  ./video$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).mp4
  ```

Log from a short recording session is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[x11grab @ 0x561a723e5ac0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0+100,100':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1578693116.465807, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 29.97 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Unknown decoder 'libx264'
simon@studio:~$ ffmpeg  -video_size 1280x720   -f x11grab  -i ${DISPLAY}+100,100  -vcodec libx264 -threads 0  ./video$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[x11grab @ 0x558225bc29a0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0+100,100':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1578693132.513351, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 29.97 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to './video2020-01-10-14-52-12.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Past duration 0.806847 too large     256kB time=00:00:00.43 bitrate=4835.3kbits/s dup=16 drop=0 speed=0.207x    
frame=  371 fps= 29 q=-1.0 Lsize=     639kB time=00:00:12.27 bitrate= 426.6kbits/s dup=16 drop=14 speed=0.971x    
video:634kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.813096%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] frame I:2     Avg QP:18.16  size:221502
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] frame P:93    Avg QP:14.97  size:  2007
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] frame B:276   Avg QP:20.13  size:    69
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0% 99.2%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] mb I  I16..4: 44.6%  0.0% 55.4%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.3%  P16..4:  0.7%  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.5%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.0%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.0%  L0:50.9% L1:49.0% BI: 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] coded y,u,v intra: 41.3% 37.5% 37.4% inter: 0.1% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] i16 v,h,dc,p: 58% 41%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 30% 14%  2%  4%  4%  5%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] ref P L0: 59.2%  8.8% 25.5%  6.5%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] ref B L0: 59.4% 39.0%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] ref B L1: 96.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x558225bcd360] kb/s:419.29
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Comment: Did you compile/build `ffmpeg` specifically for this machine? What options was it built with and what parameters are you using?

Comment: Show your command and the complete log.

Comment: Edits added to question.

Comment: Currently trying to build... gcc, nasm, pkg-config installed, done ./configure and it's working through make right now. Haven't added any special flags, suggestions welcome!

Comment: You will need `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libpulse`, or see [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: OK, build completed. At this point, if I drop my frame rate to 15fps, set crf to 30, and allow it to use two cores of the CPU, the result seems to avoid dropping frames, and the image quality and frame rate are sufficient for the purpose of screen capture for the purpose of showing my typing and running a few commands. Since that's the job at hand, I guess I'm no longer panicking. I also plan to buy a second memory stick, to give the motherboard the chance to do dual channel access. I'd still like to know if I can build hardware acceleration support for this hardware (I suspect not).

Comment: The decoding/encoding blocks on a modern Intel CPU are called Quicksync (qsv). On linux, they are also accessible through VAAPI. ffmpeg has support for both APIs.

Comment: Thanks Gyan, I'm poking around and found this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync which I think is what you're describing. That description quickly shards into many choices, each of which has many choices, while I'm trying to follow this, does anyone have any guidance on which parts I actually need, and in which order I should build them, to make ffmpeg use this hardware?

Comment: I'm inclined, at the moment, to think I need "libva" but it's not clear why I might choose any particular one (or if i need all of) MSDK, libva, i965driver, and/or iHD driver.

Comment: I've established that I need "libmfx" which this describes fairly accurately: https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/wiki/Build-Media-SDK-on-Ubuntu

This enabled me to build it, now I'm building ffmpeg, including the --enable-libmfx flag, and making sure that the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable includes the resulting /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib/pkgconfig directory which is where this put its output. So far the build is looking promising (it at least quit saying "libmfx not found" :)

Comment: I've built a bunch of stuff now: libva, gmmlib, intel-media-driver, libmfx, and ffmpeg. I now show that the encoders: h264_qsv, hevc_qsv, mjpeg_qsv, and mpeg2_qsv are all known to ffmpeg, but I have not been able to make it do anything useful. I think at this point, I need to open a new question.